# Como realizar o parse de uma string tendo como separador espaço duplo a esquerda de um caracter?

Tags: php

Estou com dificuldade para realizar o parse de uma string, de modo a transformar a mesma em um array associativo. Para exemplificar, veja um exemplo da string citada:

```
Titulo  Valor  Desc
item1   10     Descrição aqui
novo aqui     AB  Mensagem
Label  text_1      Descrição...
```

*Obs: cada linha da string acima está lendo processada horizontalmente, isso ocorre pois o processo transforma cada linha em um array e a processa individualmente.*

Na primeira linha tenho o cabeçalho das colunas, já nas linhas seguintes tenho os valores, que podem conter múltiplos espaços a esquerda da coluna. Entretanto, ao observar, podemos notar que a esquerda de cada coluna existem 2 espaços em branco, o que acaba por ser um delimitador (separador) de colunas.

Não consegui criar uma regex que consiga extrair os valores. Meu objetivo final seria um array como este:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
          'Título' => 'item1',
          'Valor' => '10',
          'Desc' => 'Descrição aqui',
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
        //...
```

Comment: Tem certeza que no arquivo são espaços em branco mesmo? Se forem espaços, o que deverá acontecer caso algum valor possua 2 ou mais espaços seguidos, algo como `"Anderson      Woss"`? É apenas um valor.

Comment: Sim, certeza que são espaços em branco. Os valores quando são inseridos não podem conter múltiplos espaços em branco entre os caracteres, porém, não sei por qual motivo, podem conter infinitos espaços a direita. Porém, antes de cada nova coluna sempre haverá 2 espaços em branco.

Answer (score 1):

Regex nunca foi meu forte, mas depois de pesquisar varias exemplos, cheguei a uma possível solução:

```
preg_split('/\s\s+/', $string_aqui);
```

Nos testes iniciais funcionou.

Comment: Poderia ser apenas `\s{2,}` que também casa com 2 ou mais espaços em branco (incluindo quebras de linha, tabulações, etc)

Answer (score 0):

```
//A string inicial
$data = "Titulo  Valor  Desc
item1   10     Descrição aqui
novo aqui     AB  Mensagem
Label  text_1      Descrição...";

//Divide a string pelas quebras de linha
$rows = explode("\n", $data);

//Array com o cabeçalho
$header = array_map(
    //Executa a função trim em todas as string resultantes
    "trim",
    //Divide por dois espaços
    explode(
        "  ",
        //Pega a primeira linha (isso já remove ela do array "$rows")
        array_shift($rows)
    )
);

//Cria uma variável para guardar os dados organizados
$parsed = array();

//Percorre as linhas
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $row = array_map(
        //Executa a função trim em todas as string resultantes
        "trim",
        //Filtra o array para remover índices em branco
        array_filter(
            //Divide por dois espaços
            explode("  ", $row),
            function($v) {
                return $v !== "";
            }
        )
    );

    //Cria um novo array a partir de dois,
    //o primeiro será usado para os índices
    //e o segundo para os valores
    $parsed[] = array_combine($header, $row);
}

//Mostra o resultado
print_r($parsed);
```

O resultado do `print_r`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Titulo] => item1
            [Valor] => 10
            [Desc] => Descrição aqui
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Titulo] => novo aqui
            [Valor] => AB
            [Desc] => Mensagem
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Titulo] => Label
            [Valor] => text_1
            [Desc] => Descrição...
        )

)
```

Como pode ver não é necessário expressões regulares

A função `trim` é executada para remover possíveis espeços após e antes da coluna, por exemplo, `" text_1 "` vira `"text_1"`

A função `array_filter` é executada para remover possíveis índices vazios, por exemplo, `["Label", "", "", "text_1", "Descrição..."]` vira `["Label", "text_1", "Descrição..."]`

Se quiser usar expressões regulares...

```
$data = "Titulo  Valor  Desc
item1   0     Descrição aqui
novo aqui     AB  Mensagem
Label  text_1      Descrição...";

$rows = explode("\n", $data);

$header = preg_split(
    "/\s{2,}/",
    trim(
        array_shift($rows)
    )
);

$parsed = array();

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $parsed[] = array_combine(
        $header,
        preg_split(
            "/\s{2,}/",
            $row
        )
    );
}

print_r($parsed);
```

A ideia é mais ou menos a mesma, só que o `preg_split` já faz o trabalho do `explode`, `array_filter` e `array_map` + `trim`. O resultado final é o mesmo

Comment: Só tome muito cuidado com o `array_filter`, pois `array_filter(['0'])` retorna `[]`. Se existir na *string* a linha `foo  0  bar` o código acusará erro, pois após o filtro restaria apenas `['foo', 'bar']`, https://ideone.com/B39sFi.

Comment: Bom ter avisado @AndersonCarlosWoss, achei que, como string, não removia, apenas como inteiro

Comment: existe uma outra complicação, identifiquei que podem haver casos onde a coluna pode conter valor vazio, agora acredito que o parse tenha se tornado ainda mais complicado.

Comment: Eu diria impossível, não tem como saber se aquele espeço vazio é uma coluna vazia ou não se a quantidade de espaços é variável (de 2 a infinito), você até pode saber, pela quantidade de itens no array, que está faltando uma coluna em algum lugar, mas qual lugar? Sugiro alterar o método que cria esses dados